# How to run an array of requests with rxjs like forkJoin and combineLatest but without having to wait for ALL to complete before seeing the results?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

So imagine you have an `array` of URLs:

```
urls: string[]
```

You make a collection of requests (in this example I am using Angular's HTTPClient.get which returns an Observable)

```
const requests = urls.map((url, index) => this.http.get<Film>(url)
```

Now I want to **execute this requests concurrently** but **not wait for all response to see everything**. In other words, if I have something like `films$: Observable<Film[]>`, I want `films$` to update **gradually** every time a response arrives.

Now to simulate this, you can update the `requests` above into something like this

```
const requests = urls.map((url, index) => this.http.get<Film>(url).pipe(delay((index + 1)* 1000))
```

With the above array of `Observable`s you should get data from each request one by one since they aren't requested at the same time. Note that this is just faking the different times of arrival of data from the individual requests. The requests itself should be done concurrently.

The goal is to update the elements in `films$` every time value emitted by any of the requests.

So before I had something like this when I misunderstood how `combineLatest` works

```
let films$: Observable<Film[]> = of([]);
const requests = urls.map(url => this.http.get<Film>(url)
.pipe(
  take(1),
 // Without this handling, the respective observable does not emit a value and you need ALL of the Observables to emit a value before combineLatest gives you results.
 // rxjs EMPTY short circuits the function as documented. handle the null elements on the template with *ngIf. 
  catchError(()=> of(null))
));
// Expect a value like [{...film1}, null, {...film2}] for when one of the URL's are invalid for example.
films$ = combineLatest(requests);
```

I was expecting the above code to update `films$` gradually, overlooking a part of the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest)

> To ensure the output array always has the same length, `combineLatest` **will actually wait for all input Observables to emit at least once, before it starts emitting results**.

Which is not what I was looking for.

If there is an rxjs *operator* or *function* that can achieve what I am looking for, I can have a cleaner template with simply utilizing the `async` pipe and not having to handle `null` values and failed requests.

I have also tried

```
this.films$ = from(urls).pipe(mergeMap(url => this.http.get<Film>(url)));
```

and

```
this.films$ = from(requests).pipe(mergeAll());
```

which isn't right because the returned value type is `Observable<Film>` instead of `Observable<Film[]>` that I can use on the template with `*ngFor="let film of films$ | async"`. Instead, if I subscribe to it, it's as if I'm listening to a socket for one record, getting updates realtime (the individual responses coming in). I can manually subscribe to any of the two and make an `Array.push` to a separate property `films: Film[]` for example, but that defeats the purpose (use `Observable` on template with `async` pipe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) operator will work nicely for you here:

```js
const makeRequest = url => this.http.get<Film>(url).pipe(
  catchError(() => EMPTY))
);

films$: Observable<Film[]> = from(urls).pipe(
  mergeMap(url => makeRequest(url)),
  scan((films, film) => films.concat(film), [])
);
```

Flow:

- [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) emits urls one at a time
- [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) subscribes to "makeRequest" and emits result into stream
- [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) accumulates results into array and emits each time a new emission is received

---

To preserve order, I would probably use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) since it emits an array in the same order as the input observables.  We can start each observable with `startWith(undefined)`, then filter out the undefined items:

```js
const requests = urls.map(url => this.http.get<Film>(url).pipe(startWith(undefined));

films$: Observable<Film[]> = combineLatest(requests).pipe(
  map(films => films.filter(f => !!f))
);
```

Comment: bruh...  give me that 

Comment: How would you ensure that the order of the data coming will follow the order of the URLs? I have my way on doing it by replacing the `array.concat` part with a few more lines. Just curious on how you would do it yourself.

Comment: I’d probably just use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) in that case.  I added an example.